# Filtering data using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have data set and I would like to apply filter with special conditions. I would prefer awk solution, but any other bash solution are accepted. File is tab separate and output should be the tab sep too.

file1:

```
20  HIGH    15  down    -
90  LOW 20  up  -
100 LOW 25  syn benign
50  LOW 40  syn -
10  HIGH    10  down    -
10  LOW 50  down    -
5   PATHOGENIC  45  no  -
100 HIGH    40  no  -
20  LOW 30  int benign
5   LOW 25  int -
```

I need to filter data by conditions:

```
1. Allays keep row where $2 == HIGH and PATHOGENIC
2. Remove $1 > 20
3. Remove $3 <= 20
4. Remove $4 == down
5. Remove $4 == up
6. Remove $4 == int && $5 == benign
```

So Output:

```
20  HIGH    15  down    -
10  HIGH    10  down    -
5   PATHOGENIC  45  no  -
100 HIGH    40  no  -
5   LOW 25  int -
```

My try was:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{if($1 >= 20 && $3 <= 20); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' | awk -v OFS="\t" '{if($4 != down); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' | awk -v OFS="\t" '{if($4 != up); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' > output
```

I am not able to implement `1.condition` and `6.condition`. Also I believe that this filtering can be done without pipping.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: the output contradicts with your conditions. Show the valid output

Comment: It is correct. Last row is appear because 6. condition is apply only when $4 == int && $5 == benign..

Comment: Output is correct - I keep HIGH and PATHOGENIC and last row is not under the condition $4 == int && $5 == benign.

Comment: Sorry I am also change 2. condition $1>20

Comment: @Geroge: Update the input and question details _once_ and don't keep on changing it

Comment: @Inian I just update it in text - your solution was OK! But I can not view it anymore.

Comment: @Geroge: Use my answer below and tweak it to whatever condition you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Purely* based on your input filtering conditions alone, your `awk` command should like this and you *don't* have to cascade multiple pipe commands,

```
awk -v FS="\t" '($2 ~ /HIGH|PATHOGENIC/) || ( !($1 >=20) && !($3<=20) && !($4 ~ /up|down/) && !(($4=="int") && ($5=="benign")))' file
```

The lines that *ideally* matches all your filtering conditions from your given input is

```
20      HIGH    15      down    -
10      HIGH    10      down    -
5       PATHOGENIC      45      no      -
100     HIGH    40      no      -
5       LOW     25      int     -
```

Comment: Sorry a change 1.condition - keep HIGH + PATHOGENIC.